# Delay showing a single item in a page

Tags: php

I am building a puzzle page with PHP and I want just one part of the page to be hidden and then shown (a hint for the puzzle). I know this can be easily done with JavaScript, but then the hint can be easily seen in the source code.

I have experimented with sleep() but that delays the whole page loading.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Lookup for ajax

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into how that works

Answer (score 0):

You would need to render the page without the hint first (no PHP sleep call). You will then also a need to add some method of requesting the hint (e.g. a link/button) on the client/browser side so that the server could respond with a new page including the hint. Using a link/button/form would work if you are not able to use JavaScript.

If you are able to use JavasScript, then you could retrieve the hint from the server using the JavaScript Fetch API and then add the hint to the webpage dynamically on some user action (e.g. user clicks on “show hint”).

Comment: I am happy to use JavaScript. The hint is stored in a MySQL database, and I don't want people to be able to find it in the source of the page before the elapsed time is up.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the AJAX request or Fetch API method to work within a function, which I needed to do use the setTimeout to get the delay. So I used the setTimeOut get AJAX to get the text from the php file, and built the day into the php file using sleep().